# Почему долго открывается div с display:none?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Есть div с `display:none`. Внутри блока картинка размером 1200*4000px.
При клике на кнопку блок получает `display:block`, но по первому клику слишком долго открывается. По второму клику открывается мгновенно. Как сделать мгновенное открытие?

Comment: Каким образом картинка вставлена?!фоном или через img?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Насколько я знаю, нынче браузеры могут не грузить изображение, если оно внутри блока с `display:none`.

При первом клике у вас происходит загрузка изображения, а при всех последующих уже нет, поэтому и мгновенно.